# Ternary expression assigned by rvalue doesn't use move asssignment operator

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

Anyone knows why the following code doesn't compile:

```
[hidden]$ g++ -v |& tail -n 1
gcc version 4.8.1 20130603 (Red Hat 4.8.1-1) (GCC)
[hidden]$ cat c.cpp
struct X {
  X() = default;
  X(const X&) = default;
  X(X&&) = default;
  X& operator=(const X&) = delete;
  X& operator=(X&&) = default;
};

void f(bool t) {
  X a, b;
  (t ? a : b) = X();
}

[hidden]$ g++ -std=c++11 -c c.cpp
c.cpp: In function ‘void f(bool)’:
c.cpp:11:15: error: use of deleted function ‘X& X::operator=(const X&)’
   (t ? a : b) = X();
               ^
c.cpp:5:6: error: declared here
   X& operator=(const X&) = delete;
      ^
c.cpp:11:15: error: use of deleted function ‘X& X::operator=(const X&)’
   (t ? a : b) = X();
               ^
c.cpp:5:6: error: declared here
   X& operator=(const X&) = delete;
      ^
```

Isn't that `X()` rvalue so the move assignment operator should be called in this case?  What section in C++11 standard talks about the case ternary expression assigned by rvalue?

Note: the ternary expression is lvalue in this case because if I change the `= delete` to `= default`, it compiles.

Comment: This actually might be a gcc bug it compile fine on clang

Comment: Does `*(t ? &a : &b) = X();` work?

Comment: @JonathanPotter, yes, this one works.

Comment: Can anyone confirm the difference between clang and gcc is due to the bug in gcc, while clang is correct that the code is supposed to work in C++11.

Comment: Most definitely a bug in the GCC.

Comment: The sections in the Standard relevant here are: [expr.cond]/4 "If the second and third operands [of the conditional operator] are glvalues of the same value category and have the same type, the result is of that type and value category" (text in brackets mine). That is, the type of `(t ? a : b)` is `X` and the value category is lvalue. `X()` is a prvalue as per [expr.type.conv]/2.

Comment: I have submitted a [bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58714).

Comment: OK, my bug report was marked as duplicate, it was first reported on Apr 15, 2012; see [the bug report and the discussion here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53000).

Comment: @Ali I don't quite see why that is a duplicate. `(t ? a : b).operator=( X() );` compiles fine on g++4.8.1. The problem is not the value category of the conditional operator expression here, but the overload resolution for the assignment operator.

Comment: @DyP  Thanks, yes, you are right. One of the gcc developers thinks that too; my bug report is marked as new at the moment. I have changed the summary of the bugreport to [**Bogus overload resolution for the assignment operator in assignment to a conditional**](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58714).

Comment: @Ali: Do you want to post an answer, stating that this is a bug, so we can get this question out of the unanswered queue?

Comment: Woo, didn't know about the special default and delete member functions in C++11. Oh, and good job finding a bug =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a bug in the compiler, see [Bogus overload resolution for the assignment operator in assignment to a conditional](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58714), it still fails in gcc 4.9.

The problem is not with the ternary operator but that the overload resolution ends up at the wrong assignment operator.